# How to display data resulting from POST in django view?

Tags: django, post, httpresponse, render-to-response

I have a form that takes a path as input, analyzes files and subfolders in that directory, stores information in a database, then displays some statistics to the user about the files just parsed.  This is done currently using a Django view and render_to_response.

According to everything I have read, it's incorrect to use anything other that HttpResponseRedirect when dealing with a POST, as a page generated with POST data would resubmit the form if the page were refreshed.

My issue here is that there's a large amount of summary data ultimately displayed as a result of analyzing files on the provided path.  How can I display that data with an httpResponseRedirect?  Sending it as GET parameters using `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse` seems infeasible due to the amount of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the data on request.session

http://www.djangobook.com/en/beta/chapter12/#cn36

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: I hadn't thought of this.  request.session is maintained on the server side, and not something actually sent around with the request itself, so this would allow me to store swaths of data generated in this report and redirect to a page that displays it.  I'm new to web development, and this doesn't seem like the intended use of sessions, but it does seem to be a relatively elegant solution to this problem.  Thanks.

Comment: This method ended up being really smooth.  I just put the results object I created in request.session and then access it in the view I redirect to.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your POST handle creates some databse object out of a submitted form data, is this correct? If so, then you can do something like this (:

```
    my_obj = MyModel.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data) # This is the part yuo already have, most probably expressed with some other code, but still..
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/url/to/redirect/?id=%d' % obj.id)
```

The redirect like should in fact use [reverse()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#reverse) function, and I think that you should have an URL for editing MyModel objects. Then you could do:

```
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('edit-mymodel', (), {'id': obj.id}))
```

The relevant URL would look like:

```
url('^edit/mymodel/(?P<id>\d+)$', 'apps.myapp', name='edit-mymodel')
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, but the actual behavior here is to parse thousands of log files, creating thousands of objects in a database, and then display verbose summary statistics.  For that reason it's hard to see how I could point to a single object, unless I were to create an object specifically for the result of this operation.  That would maybe be the best long term solution to this.

Comment: Well, it looks like a natural example of batching - add `Batch` model and make each individual object point to it with ForeignKey, then use `batch.id` for redirection.

Answer (score 0):

A rough but simple solution is to write your data in a json text file and then read it in your redirect page (this will also save you from rebuilding data on refreshing the page)